# Как склеить вектор векторов в один вектор с помощью transform_reduce?

Tags: c++, transform, map-reduce

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<vector<string>> vv = {
            {"aaaaaa"s, "bbbbbb"s, "cccccc"s},
            {"dddddd"s, "eeeeee"s, "ffffff"s, "jjjjjj"s}
    };

    vector<string> v;

    // ...

    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
    return 0;
}

// Вывод:
// aaaaaa bbbbbb cccccc dddddd eeeeee ffffff jjjjjj
```

Нужно с помощью transform_reduce (или любого другого параллельного алгоритма, относящегося к концепции MapReduce), получить в стадии reduce один вектор строк из вектора векторов строк. Контейнер может быть любым, не обязательно вектор.

Размеры вложенных векторов могут отличаться.

Comment: какой бы алгоритм не выбрали, все равно элементы есть вектора, и придется написать  функтор/лямбду захватывающщую результирующий вектор и добавляющую в нем содержимое элемента вектора).

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, да, это дело нехитрое, но весь фокус в том как это сделать в reduce стадии параллельного алгоритма..

Comment: Зачем? Проще создать итератор последовательного доступа, который представит ваш вектор векторов в единого контейнера. Ещё: зачем параллелить копирование памяти, которое от этого никак не выиграет?

Comment: Ручное разделяй и властвуй на `vector<list<string>>`. Вектор разделяем на две половины, рекурсивно склеиваем списки в половинах. Результаты половин склеиваем через `splice`. Тут нет будет лишних копий, но надо писать и параллелить руками.

Comment: Порядок элементов в результате важен?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, нет, порядок не имеет значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // операция склеивания двух списков в один
    auto list_splice=[]( list<string> lhs, list<string> rhs ) -> list<string>
    {
        lhs.splice( lhs.end(), rhs );
        return lhs;
    };

    list<string> l = std::reduce( execution::par_unseq, ll.begin(), ll.end(), list<string>{}, list_splice);
```

Comment: отличное решение, спасибо!

Comment: При распарралеливании алгоритма нужно ли применять синхронизацию для доступа к `list<string> l` в лямбде?

Comment: если я правильно понимаю, аргумент init в алгоритме reduce - в данном случае `list<string>{}`, который накапливает список, распараллеливается самим алгоритмом reduce и синхронизировать доступ не нужно, верно? А если бы этот список для накопления был захвачен лямбдой по ссылке, тогда было бы нужно, да?

Comment: Синхронизацию в данном случае применять ненужно, посокльку параллельно выполняемые участки кода не обращаются к одним переменным. (Лямбда ничаго не захватывает, а аргументы - перданы по значению.)  l-в лямбде это отдельная переменная (переименовал для ясности). В слачае  параллельного суммирования, списокв накопления - несоклько (оттельные для кадого потока), которые потом суммирубтся между собой. init прибавляется к результату (это все, что гарантируется описанием процедуры) - непраивльно думать что это и есть переменная в котой осуществляется суммирование.

Comment: Чтобы получить параллельность вся память скопирована в аргументах лямбды. Это точно будет быстрее чем последовательное слияние?

Comment: Порядок элементов в результате не гарантирован.

Comment: @Chorkov, Аргументы обязательно передавать по значению? Почему нельзя по константной ссылке? Ограничений на ЧТЕНИЕ одних и тех же участков памяти у параллельно выполняемых потоках вроде же нет? И еще, мы в лямбде опеределяем алгоритм накопления списка, это понятно, но откуда берется алгоритм для суммирования нескольких списков накопления (отдельных для кадого потока) между собой? Откуда reduce знает как два списка сложить?

Comment: Можно и по  `const &`, и по `&&`.  Совместного доступа к памяти не будет, посокльку в каждом вызове ляьмбды складываются своя пара аргументов.  С точки зрения производительности, для list, с учетов RVO/NRVO/перемещения, предпочтительно использовать передачу по значению, или по `&&`. В случае `const &`  возникнет копирование всего содержимого list в каждом вызове, что  ухудшит алгоритм до O(n^2).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Если reduce написан нормально, то лишних копирований содержимого быть не должно: ксе промежуточные результаты суммирований нужны только для передачи в следующий вызов сложения, и должны быть move-нуты при конструировании аргументов очередного вызова лямбды.

Comment: В текущем коде исходные списки останутся неизменными. Значит новый объединённый список составлен из копий узлов. Действительно быстрое решение должно разрушать исходные списки через `splice`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy если можно разрушать исходный list<list<>>, то нужно использовать `std::make_move_iterator`.  &&-в аргументах лямбды не помогут (но и не повредят).

Comment: Я полагал, что `list_splice` с аргументами-ссылками и результатом-ссылкой должна разрушить исходные списки (все кроме одного) и составить из них единый список. Но я не знаю не приведут ли подобные вольности к UB в `std::reduce`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy UB не будет. Но как вы заставите reduce использовать ссылку для временных переменных?

Comment: Верну референс из лямбды. Или не сработает?

Comment: Не работает. :(

Comment: И все-таки, откуда reduce знает как сложить два списка при суммировании нескольких списков накопления (отдельных для кадого потока) между собой?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <execution>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    list<list<string>> ll = {
            {"aaaaaa"s, "bbbbbb"s, "cccccc"s},
            {"dddddd"s, "eeeeee"s, "ffffff"s, "ggggggg"s}
    };

    list<string> l;

    transform_reduce(execution::par, ll.begin(), ll.end(), ""s, std::plus<string>(), [&l](list<string> in) {
        l.insert(l.end(), in.begin(), in.end());
        return ""s;
    });

    copy(l.begin(), l.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
// Вывод:
// aaaaaa bbbbbb cccccc dddddd eeeeee ffffff ggggggg
```

Вот такой вариант работает, но хотелось бы более элегантное решение, потому что тут костыль - пустая строка ""s складывается.

И еще вопрос, метод insert в лямбде не повлияет на распараллеливание алгоритма?

Comment: Этот вариант содержит неопределенное поведение, поскольку лямбды могут быть вызваны параллельно, а вы не применяете никакой синхронизации для доступа к `list<string> l`.